# Almost symmetric polynomial?

Tags: symmetric-polynomials

Let's say we have a polynomial $(x-y)(y-z)(x-z)$. This is not a symmetric polynomial, but it almost is. Every permutation of the variables results in a polynomial whose factors are multiples of the factors of the original polynomial. For example, if we send $y$ to $x$ and $x$ to $y$, we get $(y-x)(x-z)(y-z)=-1(x-y)(y-z)(x-z)$. In fact, each factor is multiplied by $1$ or $-1$. Is there a name for this kind of polynomial?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called an [alternating polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_polynomial), or sometimes a [skew-symmetric polynomial](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Symmetric_polynomial).

Whenever a polynomial reacts to *every* permutation of the variables by multiplication of with some constant factor, it must be either symmetric or alternating. This is because the constant factors for each permutation must constitute a one-dimensional representations of $S_n$, and the only such representations are the trivial representation and the sign representation.